# telegram, slack, skype won't run if I put them on startup applications

Tags: 16.04, startup, skype, startup-applications, slack

I have run telegram, slack, skype on startup application ubuntu 16.04

[image]

But, the icon doesn't appear in taskbar (notification area). Howver, it appear as run application

```
 $ ps ax | grep skype
 3854 ?        SLl    1:59 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --executed-from=/home/pujangga --pid=3847
 3864 ?        S      0:00 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=zygote --no-sandbox
 3985 ?        Sl     1:33 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=renderer --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --ms-disable-indexeddb-transaction-timeout --no-sandbox --service-pipe-token=EF831309DDA5DEFF9BDFE0351F93886A --lang=en-US --app-path=/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar --node-integration=false --webview-tag=true --no-sandbox --native-window-open --preload=/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/Preload.js --background-color=#fff --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --enable-compositor-image-animations --service-request-channel-token=EF831309DDA5DEFF9BDFE0351F93886A --renderer-client-id=4 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101 --skype-process-type=Main
 9924 pts/16   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto skype
```

When I try to run it unity dash, it won't start too. I need to `killall skypeforlinux` to make it run through dash menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by change the command to `bash -c "killall skypeforlinux ; skypeforlinux"`

[image]